# Django url regular expression is not getting matched

Tags: regex, django, django-urls

I need to match the url encoded spaces in the url that is %20.

My url would be something like

```
http://domain/something/hello%20world
```

Here is the my url conf and view

```
url(r'^regtest/(\w+[%20]?\w+)', views.regView)
```

View:

```
   def regView(request, x, y=None):                                      
    print x, 'and', y                                              
    return HttpResponse('+OK')
```

Here are the logs when I got the hit from the url

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/regtest/hello%20world

hello and None
[13/Jan/2014 02:12:31] "GET /regtest/hello%20world HTTP/1.1" 200 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pattern `[%20]` matches `%`, `2` or `0`.

Use following regular expression instead to match word character (`\w`) or (`|`), `%20`:

```
r'^regtest/((?:\w|%20)+)'
```

---

```
>>> import re
>>> matched = re.search(r'regtest/((?:\w|%20)+)', 'regtest/hello%20world')
>>> matched.group(1)
'hello%20world'
```

**UPDATE**

`%20` is interpreted by Django and decoded as a space (). So you should match space instead of `%20`.

```
r'^regtest/([\w\s]+)'
```

Comment: It is not even getting matched when I use it in the  url conf.
I did cross check that one,

Comment: I tried the following regular experession too.
(\w+(%20)?\w+)